# Unable to create folder recursively in remote server using PHP

Tags: php, permissions, sftp

I was trying to create directory in a remote SFTP server using PHP.
But then always failed to create.

Following is what I tried.

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
$path = "images/vehicle/car/sports/";
if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)){
    echo "connected\n";
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
    if (file_exists('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . '/' . $path)) {
        echo "present\n";
    } else {
        ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, $path);
        $contents = file_get_contents('car.jpeg');
        file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/$path/car.jpeg", $contents);
    }
} else {
    echo "connection failed\n";
}
```

Ques 1. Am unable to create directory. Is there any issue in this script?

Ques 2. Am able to create each folder one by one like this,

```
ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, '/images');
ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, '/images/vehicle');
ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, '/images/vehicle/car');
```

So is this anything permission related issue?

Ques 3. file_exists condition always failing. Is there another method to check directory existing or not in remote server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation clearly states that you have to add an explicit "recursive flag", since the default is *non recursive* behavior.

That means you should use something like that:

```
ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, $path, 0700, true);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp-mkdir.php

Comment: Yes, this is working fine to create recursive folder structure. But then still unable to check folder exist or not. Any idea on that. Thanks for the answer.